# How to use @bind-PropertyName withing @Body

Tags: bind, blazor

I have a project with many pages. The structure is: Parent page that includes Menu, header, and context. The task is to send some string from the context page to the header. The question is: how do I use `@bind-PropertyName` on `@Body`?

MainLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">

    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <Header PageTitle="@_PageTitle" />
    </div>
        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
</div>
@code{
    private string _PageTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Header component:

```
<div>Title: @PageTitle</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Context component:

```
@page "/plainpage"
<div> @PageTitle </div>

<Content />

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string PageTitle { get; set; } = "Plain Page";

    public EventCallback<string> Initialized { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        OnPageInitialized(); 
    }

    private Task OnPageInitialized()
    {
        return Initialized.InvokeAsync(PageTitle);
    }
}
```

If instead of `@Body` I had `<PlainPage />` component, I would do `<PlainPage @bind-PageTitle="_PageTitle" />`. But how do I do it with `@Body`?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629257/change-visibility-of-nav-item-in-blazor-menu/59651797#59651797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a CascadingValue which the "context" pages can use to call back to the layout.

So, in your MainLayout, wrap @Body in a CascadingValue

```html
<div class="content px-4">
  <CascadingValue Value=@this>
  @Body
  </CascadingValue>
</div>
```

In the `@code` of your MainLayout create a public method

```csharp
public void SomeMethod(string SomeString)
{
  // Do Something With SomeString like setting PageTitle
}
```

And in the code of your "context" use a CascadingParameter

```csharp
[CascadingParameter] MainLayout mainLayout {get;set;}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
  mainLayout.SomeMethod(PageTitle);
}
```