# Change visibility of nav item in blazor menu based on condition after index load

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have one Menu in Left Navigation, that will be hide/display based on isAdmin Condition.
I am getting the value of isAdmin on Index.Razor page. Now I want to re-render the left navigation if isAdmin is true, Below Nav item should be visible

```
@if (isAdmin)
                {
                 <a class="nav-items" target="_blank">
                        <div style="width:40px;">
                            <i title="Security" class="fab fa-expeditedssl fa-fw" style="color: white; font-size: 30px;"></i>
                        </div>
                        <span class="nav-items-text" style="color:white; visibility:@Visibility">Security</span>
                </a>   
                }
```

[Change visibility of nav item in blazor menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629257/change-visibility-of-nav-item-in-blazor-menu)

As suggested by above link, I created the AppStateService in Services. Below is my code for AppStateService

```
public class AppStateService
    {
        private bool isAdmin;
        public event Action OnChange;
        public bool IsAdmin
        {
            get { return isAdmin; }
            set
            {
                if (isAdmin != value)
                {
                    isAdmin = value;
                    NotifyStateChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
    }
```

On Index page, I used and assign the

```
@inject AppStateService AppStateService
AppStateService.IsAdmin = true;
```

On Left Navigation Component, I used

```
@inject AppStateService AppStateService
@implements IDisposable
```

Left Navigation Component

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            AppStateService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
        }


public void Dispose()
        {
            AppStateService.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
        }
```

added in Startup class also.

But now how will I get the Value of isAdmin in left Navigation, from Index.Razor page to display / hide the nav item.

Comment: Where are your roles coming from? There maybe a far more robust solution.

Comment: Role is coming from different api of 3rd party

Comment: @PankajGoel, Did you check my answer, can you give me an update?

Comment: @user13256346 Yea.. I am checking it.. But it passing false to IsAdmin.

Comment: No sorry I am not available for that right now!, Can you share you index page where did you include `Navigation Component` ?

Comment: @user13256346 I am not including Navigation component on index. My navigation component is in shared folder and this navigation is included in the MainLayout in shared.

Comment: Ah, Then you need to move  code of `index page` in the answer down to your ` MainLayout` ?

Comment: @user13256346  but then how to pass the value of true / false came from API result on index page to main layout
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)
  {
    AppStateService.IsAdmin = isAdmin (true or false); // Dynamic value based on api result
    AppStateService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245876/discussion-between-user13256346-and-pankaj-goel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation bar code:

```
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => appStateService.OnChange += OnAppStateChanged; 

    private void OnAppStateChanged()
        => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
        => appStateService.OnChange -= OnAppStateChanged;
```

And a test page:

```
@page "/"
@inject AppStateService appStateService; 

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code{

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.appStateService.IsAdmin = false;
        await this.GetIsAdmin();
    }

    private async ValueTask GetIsAdmin()
    {
        //emulate an async API call
        await Task.Delay(500);
        var isAdmin = (Random.Shared.Next(0, 2)) == 0;
        this.appStateService.IsAdmin = isAdmin;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have any button on index page.. on index page, i am hitting a API and based on that API in the result, i am getting value of isAdmin.. Based on that value i have to show/hide nav item in nav component

Comment: So write some code in `OnInitializedAsync` to hit the API and then set the `AppStateService` value,  The button is just a quick demonstrator to show the display working,

Comment: OnInitializedAsync on Index page, i am already hitting the API and from that API i am value of isAdmin.. Now i want to use the value of isAdmin in leftNavigation compoenent.. Based on that value, my menu will be hidden or display

Comment: See revised answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are in the right way, but try to add your code in Index page and not in Navigation Component.
***Index page***

```
@inject AppStateService AppStateService
@implements IDisposable

protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)
  {
    AppStateService.IsAdmin = true;
    AppStateService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
  }
}

public void Dispose()
{
   AppStateService.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
}
```

Navigation Component, kept the same.

```
@if (AppStateService.IsAdmin)
 {
    <a class="nav-items" target="_blank">
       <div style="width:40px;">
         <i title="Security" class="fab fa-expeditedssl fa-fw" style="color: white; font-size: 30px;"></i>
       </div>
       <span class="nav-items-text" style="color:white; visibility:@Visibility">Security</span>
    </a>   
}
```